# How to connect ios cordova app to apple push notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova app with cordova-plugin-firebasex. It works perfect on ios and android except one thing:

**there are no system notifications on ios**.

My app receive data messages from firebase, but I can't send a notification from firebase console to ios system notification center.

1. I created Apple developer cert and install it on my Mac
2. I created iOS distribution cert and install it on my Mac
3. I created a new identifier with push notifications
4. Created two certs for push notifications (dev & dist) and install it on my Mac
5. Created profiles for dist and dev and install it on my Mac
6. Created new cordova project and install cordova-plugin-firebasex. All Pod's installed succesfully.
7. Open project in XCode and in Signing & Capabilities download and select my profiles for debug and release
8. Push notifications is present in Signing & Capabilities.

Then I created one Big APNS Button in my app to show my apns token, created archive and upload it to TestFlight.

But when I install my app on my iPhone SE - I don't see a dialog about allow push notifications. And when I press my Big APNS Button - I see a `null`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED

```
FirebasePlugin.grantPermission(function(hasPermission){
    console.log("Permission was " + (hasPermission ? "granted" : "denied"));
});
```